# PHP Run background script from cli script

Tags: php, command-line-interface

From a php script I need to launch a new php script in background.
I expect this to be working:

```
shell_exec("php mySecondScript.php &");
```

Execution of main script hangs and secondScript is not even started. Of course if I remove '&' the script is executed, but synchronously. Any reason for this?

Comment: It does; unfortunatly i was not precise in following redirect syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't redirect output of command.

```
shell_exec("php mySecondScript.php > /dev/null &");
```

Comment: Actually I was.. but using "&> myLogFile" it's not working. Using "> myLogFile 2>&1" it is. That was really hard to figure out, and still I wonder why